# How to prove that the set of all $a+b\sqrt{2}$ is an algebraic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I'm trying to find a polynomial $f(X)\in \mathbb{Q}[X]$ such that $f(a+b\sqrt{2})=0$. However, because $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ is a field, I can't have $\sqrt{2}$ vanished by multiplication. So I try to use addition, and eventually vanish $\sqrt{2}$ but fail to get a zero solution, leaving a term without $\sqrt{2}$. Could anyone tell me the very polynomial $f(X)\in \mathbb{Q}[X]$ such that $f(a+b\sqrt{2})=0$?

Comment: Put $x=a+b\sqrt {2}$ and square it.

Comment: @Paramanand Singh: I did square it and failed to have the term containing $\sqrt{2}$ vanished.

Comment: Well we have $x=a+b\sqrt {2},x^2=a^2+2b^2+2ab\sqrt{2}$. Multiply first equation with $2a$ and subtract the resulting one from the second equation. This gets rid of the $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: @ Paramanand Singh: In fact, I have tried this way before. But still can't get the zero solution. I have mentioned in my question that there left a term without $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: You should say that $a,b\in\Bbb Q$, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x=a+b\sqrt{2}$

$$ x-a=b\sqrt2 $$

Square both sides

$$ (x-a)^2-2b^2=0 $$

The LHS is now having rational coefficents

Answer (score 1):

If $x = a + b \sqrt{2}$ then $(x-a)^2 = 2b^2$ and $(x-a)^2 - 2b^2 = 0$.  The left hand side of this equation is a polynomial with rational coefficients if $a$ and $b$ are rational numbers.